# Rretrieve threads of a process in Windows

Tags: windows, operating-system

I am doing a Systems Programming task on Windows, and I have to list all the threads spawned by a particular process. Is there a function for this task in `WIN32` API? I looked at the [thread and process page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but couldn't find the relevant function.

Comment: What so you intend to do with those threads once you find them? In general you should let them do their thing and not try to mess with them.

Comment: @RaymondChen hey thanks. I am only trying to find the information about a process once it has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft's [Tool Help library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It gives you what you need.

BTW, check out [ProcessExporer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), it provides a lot of details about running proceses.